# JQuery: Run Code After Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, window, delay

Here's the code:

```
window.location.replace('http://thewebsiteurl');
```

How would I run this code after a 0.1 second delay?

-Thanks

Comment: Also, see [How to delay execution in between the following in my javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/5990725), [Javascript - Wait 5 seconds before executing next line](//stackoverflow.com/q/14226803), [How to set time delay in javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/17883692), [Put a Delay in Javascript](//stackoverflow.com/q/1183872)

Answer (score 0):

use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
setTimeout(() => window.location.replace('http://thewebsiteurl'), 100) // in milli seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a queue:

`.delay( milliseconds [, queueName ] )`

[The delay method](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)